# C Get complete words from first 15 characters of string

Tags: c, string

I have a function that will return either the first 13 characters of a string or the second 13 characters of a string:

```
char* get_headsign_text(char* string, int position) {
  if (position == 1){
    char* myString = malloc(13);
    strncpy(myString, string, 13);
    myString[13] = '\0'; //null terminate destination
    return myString;
    free(myString);
  } else {
    char* myString = malloc(13);
    string += 13;
    strncpy(myString, string, 13);
    myString[13] = '\0'; //null terminate destination
    return myString;
    free(myString);
  }
}
```

I would like to have it so that the function will return only complete words (not cutoff words in the middle).

Example:
If the string is "Hi I'm Christopher"

```
get_headsign_text(string, 1) = "Hi I'm "
get_headsign_text(string, 2) = "Christopher"
```

So if the function would have cut within a word, instead it would cut before that last word, and if so, if it is trying to get the second 13 it would include the word that would have been cut.

Comment: "Second 13 characters" - so what if the string is more than 26?

Comment: If it's more than 26 it just disregards the 27th+ characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking various edge cases into consideration, the structure of the code needs to change considerably.

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

inline int min_int(int a, int b) {
        return a < b ? a : b;
}

inline int is_word_char(char c) {
        return isgraph(c);
}

char* get_headsign_text(char* string, int position) {
        int start_index, end_index;
        if (position == 1) {
                start_index = 0;
        } else {
                start_index = 13;
        }
        end_index = min_int(strlen(string) + 1, start_index + 13);
        start_index = min_int(start_index, end_index);
        int was_word_char = 1;
        while(start_index > 0 && (was_word_char = is_word_char(string[start_index]))) {
                --start_index;
        }
        if(!was_word_char) {
                ++start_index;
        }
        while(end_index > start_index && is_word_char(string[end_index])) {
                --end_index;
        }
        int myStringLen = end_index - start_index;
        char *myString = malloc(myStringLen + 1);
        strncpy(myString, string + start_index, myStringLen);
        myString[myStringLen] = '\0';
        return myString;
}

int main(void) {
        char s[] = "Hi, I\'m Christopher";
        char *r1 = get_headsign_text(s, 1);
        char *r2 = get_headsign_text(s, 2);
        printf("<%s>\n<%s>\n", r1, r2);
        free(r1);
        free(r2);
        return 0;
}
```

That said, there are numerous other problems/concerns with the code snippet you posted:

- In the assignment `myString[13] = '\0';`, you are assigning to memory which you have not allocated. Although you have allocated 13 bytes, `myString[13]` refers to one byte past the last allocated byte.
- Nothing after the `return` statement gets executed, and the calls to `free` are never reached.
- You shouldn't be returning a block of memory only to free it immediately! It's quite counter-productive to give something to the caller only to take it away. :)
- You do not validate the size of the string. Unless you are absolutely certain this will only be called on strings of sufficient length, your function will segfault when, say, `position` is `2` and your string buffer is only, say, `10` bytes long.

Comment: This looks great, except when you call get_headsign_text(string, 2) it appears to not include the word that would have been cut

Comment: Thank you SO much for your comments, its really helping me learn c!  And for the last point, yes I have it set so that this function is only called if the string is long enough

Comment: It looks like you are using myString before it is declared?

Comment: Now the app is crashing when I call get_headsign_text(string, 2), not sure why.  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: So since you are using malloc inside the function, when is that memory being freed?  I am calling this function several times in my program and it appears to be causing a memory leak somehow

Comment: It is the caller's responsibility to free a block of memory allocated and returned by a function. It's freed whenever your program calls `free` on the return value of this function. If you don't call `free` on every value returned from that function call, your program *will* leak memory. Which brings up another point: it would be better if the function modified the contents of its `string` argument and returned `void` (or maybe even an `int` to indicate success or failure?). There's nothing about the function which requires you to use dynamic memory.

Comment: `myString[myStringLen + 1] = '\0';` ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your last character is not a blank space `''` then it should find for trailing space and cut your string to that index.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of your spaces using an index variable. If the character count is 13, and the current character is not a space or null terminator, then adjust your character count by subtracting that and the last space index. Save the string, and then continue from the last space index.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multitude of issues.

First issue, you're free'ing after returning the myString - meaning this function will not free the string.

Second issue. You allocate 13 chars, then you set the 13rd char to null. Are you *sure* this does what you expect?

Third issue - why are you adding 13 to the string pointer? What should that do?

Lastly, you should think about which character is used to separate words - when you've figured which one that is, try to scan for it and cut your string where it is.

Comment: Sorry I'm brand new to c coding and don't really know what I'm doing. Thanks for the tips